# Convert linked images to embedded images

Tags: excel, image

i have an excel file with many images inside.

Actually, this excel files was made with HTML code that converted to excel file and the images were linked to their respective image. ( The reason i made the file with excel is because there is about 700+ images and i cant make it manually from 1. It will takes so much time to finish)

here is my excel's HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>

   <thead>          
      <tr>
         <th>No</th>
         <th>Image</th>
         <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td >1</td>
         <td><img src="56.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >2</td>
         <td><img src="57.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >3</td>
         <td><img src="58.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >4</td>
         <td><img src="59.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >5</td>
         <td><img src="60.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >6</td>
         <td><img src="61.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >7</td>
         <td><img src="62.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >8</td>
         <td><img src="63.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >9</td>
         <td><img src="64.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >10</td>
         <td><img src="65.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >11</td>
         <td><img src="66.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >12</td>
         <td><img src="67.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >13</td>
         <td><img src="68.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >14</td>
         <td><img src="69.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >15</td>
         <td><img src="70.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >16</td>
         <td><img src="71.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >17</td>
         <td><img src="72.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >18</td>
         <td><img src="73.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >19</td>
         <td><img src="74.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >20</td>
         <td><img src="75.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >21</td>
         <td><img src="76.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >22</td>
         <td><img src="77.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >23</td>
         <td><img src="78.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
         <td >24</td>
         <td><img src="79.jpg" width="200px"/></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when i save it and send the excel file to other's PC, the images will be blank. Here's the screenshot

[image]

i tried to google the problem but still i couldn't find the solution yet.

Any method to convert all the images to embedded images?

Thank you

Comment: How do you convert the HTML file to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a VBA script to convert all linked images to embedded images.

This script will have errors if there are shapes which aren't images. It also assumes that embedded images have their link in their alt text, which I found to be the case in my situation.

```
Sub INSERT_PICS()  
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
        Debug.Print shp.AlternativeText
          ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=shp.AlternativeText, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
              savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=shp.Left, Top:=shp.Top, Width:=shp.Width, Height:=shp.Height
          shp.Delete
    Next shp
 End Sub
```